# texto con marco bordeando imagen

Tags: html, css

hola estoy intentando hacer una pagina que contenga un texto con marco que envuelva una imagen a su derecha o a su izquierda, tal como la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin utilizar js, puro html y css

Comment: Por favor mira esta demo y dime si esto es lo que quieres: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/b64cc97d6882bdcc90323192ce01ff25?editors=0010

Comment: hola, mucha gracias por responder, era eso lo que queria hacer, pero sin utilizar js, puro html y css

Answer (score 0):

primero a la etiqueta `<img>` recuerda siempre envolverla con la etiqueta `<figure>`, eso es para que los navegadores sepan que es una imagen.
Lo segundo y muy importante es que a la etiqueta `<figure>` le pongas con css la propiedad `float:right;`, con esto rompes el flujo de el orden por defecto del código y por ende cumplirás tu propósito.

Te recomiendo [aprender de html, css y javascript:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC9_8nRNNHA&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BnX63lyAeV0LzLnpGudgRrK)

**Ej mas claro:**

```css
figure {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="images/pruebas.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quos quae labore cumque debitis officiis hic harum aperiam et quasi? Minus, quo nulla, corporis dignissimos illo at aspernatur laborum placeat!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, pero lo que necesito es marcar el borde del texto.el primer intento que hice fue en un div puse la imagen con estilo float right y un parrafo que envolvio a la imagen sin problemas, solo me falta hacer en CSS el borde al parrafo.